# simple_form input list array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, simple-form

How to make an adding list using simple_form?
For example, I want to add several items into my bag.
I have a model Bag and field which stores Array of Items.
I want to do editing form for list of items.

```
class Bag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :items, type: Array, default: []
end
```

Comment: Not sure i got your question, but i think what you need isn't very related to simple_form, keywords to find suitable answers should be something like :`Rails dynamic form fields ` , 'Rails javascript add field` , 'Rails JQuery add remove fields` and so on. Also look at railscasts on: complex forms and nested forms

Comment: I see, just thought maybe there where easier way to do that :) Thanks